# Only one mySQL database loses connection

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to drop one of my databases in mySQL, but I keep getting error 2013: lost connection (this occurs with other queries in this database as well). However, any other database works fine; I can perform queries and delete databases and tables easily.

I've tried googling it, but everything I've seen has essentially said that this lost connection is because of a large or complicated query.

My code is just

```
DROP DATABASE employees;
```

However, when I expand that database, it also says Tables/Views/Stored Procedures/Functions cannot be fetched, if that helps (once again, my other databases don't have this problem).

I created this database in Jupyter notebooks using mySQL python connector, and the others I created directly in mySQL, but that is the only real differentiating factor between them.

Comment: No idea what the problem is as it is only one database which gives you problems, but you should be able to just remove the employees dir in the MySQL datadir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Turns out if you're running the code in Jupyter Notebooks and try to perform any actions before closing the cursor, it won't run. (I forgot to run the cell with mycursor.close()). Thanks!